# Performance of table vs view SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

I'm working in a data warehouse that has a very large table of transactional data (hundreds of millions of rows). There are certain common ways the users want to chop up the data (see only certain transaction types, see only certain vendors, see only one month at a time, etc) and I'm trying to determine the best way to do this from a performance perspective.

The data is static, loaded monthly. So, I don't have to deal with constantly changing data.

Should I create views that only contain the desired records? Or, should I create a table and load the data for each use case?

Basically, I think my question is this: If I have a large, static table, should I write a view that filters only the records I want, and then query against that view? Or, should I create a table, load only the records I want from the main table, then query the table?

I see plenty of discussion about "views vs queries" but what I'm really asking is "query against a view vs query against a table."

Comment: Hard to say without some specifics. You can index views, so this may be useful for creating the specific views you need to get the data you need. Can you load your data into a test environment. All the answers will be in the execution plans.

Comment: The view is still going to query the table so there isn't going to be much, if any, difference here. But if the views are indexed it might help. Sadly this is just entirely too broad of a question.

Comment: Are you using the Inmon or Kimball methodology for your data warehouse architecture? Is this in SQL Server, or in SSAS?

Comment: I agree that examples would be needed of the data's use as in SQL Server you can partition "hot" and "cold" data onto separate indexes or onto separate drives depending on what you want to change.  Indexes could be separated by last 3 months of data or by a certain date etc to optimise performance.  I'd suggest a Stored procedure with indexed table value functions could be explored?

Comment: Are you using SSAS to build cubes in the warehouse?

Comment: @SeanLange Generally speaking, if you query from a view that has been built (filtered) from a table, would it be "faster" than querying from the table to achieve the same results by adding those parameters within the query? I.E. view is WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL, so you just need to select all from that view. If you query straight from the table it would be select all from table where etc...

Comment: @Simon - No a view is not stored anywhere. It is just a saved query. When you pull data from that view it runs the query against the underlying tables. Unless we are talking an indexed or materialized view. Those are entirely different animals and would be a great choice for something like you are describing.

Comment: Let me be more specific. The transaction table has 200 million rows. There are 10 transaction types. Many users only care about 2, which brings the row count down to 50 million. Should I create a view that has a WHERE Transactiontype in ('a','b') clause? Or, should I create a second table, with the same columns, but only load rows for those two types? Users will be running queries to filter and aggregate against other columns in the table: filtering for certain dates, or vendor types.

This is SQLServer 2016, not using SSAS. No other tables involved. It's totally flat, one huge table.

Comment: If they only need 2 of your types either then you index on transaction type and then create a view based on these 2 or else you index your table and persist it and then you can index that. A persisted table os "at most times" faster than a view because you can index it (you can also make indexed views) But i would make a table based on these 2 types and then index maybe on dates and vendor types, then you would have a really fast table and then you can also created views on this to make subsets.And since you use 2016 i would try columnstored index.

Answer (score 0):

I too had to transfer 86+ million rows from a transaction table to my data warehouse through SSIS package when doing I faced with ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type so eventually I modified my query in SSIS to fetch records from the transaction table batch by batch and insert in to my data warehouse.
You can also try Views with filter conditions but anyway it will lookup from base table so I go with fetch records by batch.